# Cancel blocking `poll`?

Tags: c++, c, blocking

So, I've run into this issue where I have many threads calling poll on different file descriptors. When I want to add a new one, I need to cancel one of those polls, add a new one, and continue. That alone sounds bad, but also I can't even see how to do that.

Some relevant code:

```
struct pollfd fds[size];
for(int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
    struct pollfd fd;
    fd.fd = body[i];
    fd.events = POLLIN;
    fd.revents = 0;
    fds[i] = fd;
}
if(poll(&fds[0], (nfds_t)size, -1) < 0) return NULL;
```

(I'm using this through JNI also).

I figure I could set a really low delay on poll, and call it over and over, but I think that would begin to defeat the purpose.

Comment: polling is a major CPU cycle eater.  suggest using (in a loop) select(); read().  read the man page for select() to determine how to use it.   then, by using a timeout value in the select(), there is a 'frequent' opportunity for the code to drop one or more of the current inputs and add any new ones.

Comment: send a signal? `poll()` should stop and return `EINTR`.

Comment: I think setting a time-out is the only option. I'm not sure how that defeats the purpose.

Comment: @EOF I'll try that, thank you. If you like post that as an answer ans I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send your process a signal, causing `poll()` to return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR`. The signal should obviously not cause the process to terminate, so you may need to get some `sigaction()` or `sigprocmask()`. However, any signal received between calling either of those and `poll()` may get lost, similar to `select()/pselect()`. For this reason some systems may provide additional, non-standard replacements for `poll()`, like `ppoll()`, which include a `sigset_t` to change the signal disposition atomically.

Answer (score 4):

The way you can do it is: open a socket or a pipe where, when there is a new file descriptor to add to a polling set, another thread sends some data. Thus, poll will return, you check this reserved file descriptor. If there is data, it means there is a new file descriptor to add.